# How to find the oldest link among turtles' links?

Tags: performance, netlogo, multi-agent

I need to find which link among turtle links is the oldest or newest , now I am using a property called , link-order which stores this value for each link and I find it using  min-of my-out-links [link-order]

Is there any better way to do this? Without the need to have link-order attribute for all the links?

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:turtle], which is a RDF syntax. I assume this is not relevant to your question, is it?

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant a netlogo turtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only alternative I can think of would be to have a global list of all links, and whenever a link is created, stick it on the end (and remove any `nobody` entries that have accumulated because of links dying). Then the oldest link is always the first item in the list.

Your original idea seems fine to me too though — neither approach seems obviously superior to the other. I'd probably pick your idea just because it seems a little simpler and less error-prone to code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use the current method until I find a better one, but I think the method you are suggesting can be used for the oldest link among all the links for all the turtles, which is not what I need, for each turtle I need the oldest link. In suggested method we should have a row for each turtle and the ordered set of links for that turtle, and first item of each row then will be the oldest for that turtle.